# what is the .config_p56 file in sdcard? And do you have this file too?

Tags: files, hidden

(sdcard is a symlink to storage/sdcard0)

because it starts with a dot it is hidden.To see it have viewing of hidden files enabled.It contents are empty and its properties say it takes 0bits space.Maybe my phone is compromised with malware?

Please tell me if you have this file too.

Comment: please note that storage/sdcard1 is my removable sdcard and that the only google result about this file revealed that the file on the persons phone contained a long string of random characters, possbily encrypted